# Tax not added to the base product price in cart and when placing order

Tags: cart, tax, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9.0.1 CE

I have imported products with prices that does not include tax.

And on the frontend I would like to display prices with tax added.

Until now I was able to make it work,

The prices on the frontend, 
I mean home page, category page, product page are displayed correctly with the tax added to the base product price.

When added to the cart, also with the correct price (with tax).

But when I want to go to the page of cart or place the order, the price of the product is without tax, global price is without tax. And that is incorrect.

It is French site, the tax is 20%, the settings in backend are like this : 
Configuration / Sales / Tax

**Calculation Settings**

- Tax Calculation Method Based On : Unit Price / when setting other same result
- Tax Calculation Based ON : Shipping Origin / set to France / Paris
- Catalog Prices : Excluding Tax / if changed prices on front end without tax
- Shipping Prices : Excluding Tax
- Apply Tax On : Custom price if available
- Enable Cross Border Trade : Yes

**Default Tax Destination Calculation**

- Default Country : France
- Default State : *
- Default Post Code : *

**Price Display Settings**

- Display Product Prices In Catalog : Including Tax / if changed without tax on frontend
- Display Shipping Prices : Including Tax

**Shopping Cart Display Settings**

- Display Prices : Including and Excluding Tax / strange thing is that both prices are the same (without tax)
- Display Subtotal : Including and Excluding Tax / both prices are the same (without tax)
- Display Shipping Amount : Including Tax
- Include Tax In Grand Total : Yes

**Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings**

- Display Prices : Including Tax
- Display Subtotal : Including Tax
- Display Shipping Amount : Including Tax
- Include Tax In Grand Total : Yes

**Enable FPT : NO**

I am starting to think that it could problem of the core functionality of Magento, because it almost works...

Thanks in advance for any solution...

Answer (score 6):

Well, finally it was really easy... But in fact I have lost almost one week searching the issue of this problem.

It seems that even if you will precise the tax %, in the tax rules, and you will chose tax class "Normal", the same for the product, it will not add tax to your product. It will without tax.

You have to choose tax class Shipping, for tax rule and product. And after that all works like a charm.

Comment: >spends a week trying to find a minor change that should be documented better.  Man, magento can be a major PITA.